# laravel deserialize/decode job raw body

Tags: laravel, jobs, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

i'm experiencing one problem here. Sample will speak for it self.

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
$job_details = json_decode($event->job->getRawBody(), true);

)});
```

This is how $job_details looks like:

```
'displayName' => 'App\\Jobs\\CommandJob',
  'job' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call',
  'maxTries' => 10,
  'timeout' => NULL,
  'data' => 
  array (
    'commandName' => 'App\\Jobs\\CommandJob',
    'command' => 'O:19:"App\\Jobs\\CommandJob":9:{s:32:"' . "\0" . 'App\\Jobs\\CommandJob' . "\0" . 'commandName";N;s:30:"' . "\0" . 'App\\Jobs\\CommandJob' . "\0" . 'arguments";N;s:28:"' . "\0" . 'App\\Jobs\\CommandJob' . "\0" . 'command";s:20:"google:get-campaigns";s:5:"tries";i:10;s:32:"' . "\0" . 'App\\Jobs\\CommandJob' . "\0" . 'nextCommand";a:1:{i:0;s:19:"google:get-adgroups";}s:6:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'job";N;s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";s:11:"update_data";s:5:"delay";N;}',
```

I would like to get some params from $job_details['data']['command'].
Is there some simple way to do this , or i need some home made soultion ?

Comment: I got the very similar problem and tried using the php serialize unserialize methods but seems they are not serialized with this method.

Answer (score 14):

`$event->job->getRawBody` returns a string so you can't write `$job_details['data']['command']` and you will end up with `Illegal string offset error`.

I am using Laravel 5.4 and i have managed to retrieve my `Job` instance using `$event->job->payload()` then applying the `unserialize` method according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#running-the-queue-worker).

So what i did is :

```
    $payload = $event->job->payload();

    $myJob = unserialize($payload['data']['command']);

    $myJob->getMyProperty();

    //... Just work with $myJob as if it were your job class
```

Comment: Everything else in Laravel seems so clean and elegant and this is just ... not ... but it does work!

Comment: Is this a secure way to unserialize an object?

Comment: According to the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), You should not pass untrusted user input to the `unserialize` function. You need to ensure job data was properly encoded, escaped and filtered before being stored into the DB.

Answer (score 3):

The `$job_details["data"]["command"]` is a string generated from [serialize($value)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You can [unserialize($str)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it to create the job object represented by your string. You will then have access to the properties according to the usual visibility rules.

```
$job = unserialize($job_details["data"]["command"]);
dump($job->queue;) // "update_data"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having error with an email that contained some space in it. To fix the problem and send it, I had to decode the payload of the `failed jobs` and remove the space in the email.

To do so, in `php artisan tinker`

```
// take some specific failed jobs
$failed_job = DB::table('failed_jobs')->where('id', $your_job_id)->first();
$payload = json_decode($failed_job->payload);
$obj = unserialize($payload->data->command);

   
// here I have the user content, I can see the wrong email
$user = $obj->notifiables; 
    
//update email and save
$user->email = "newemail@something"
$user->update()
```

As the last step, push again the jobs into the `queue`.